# Check window scrolltop position of page on refresh and apply classes

Tags: navigation, scrolltop, sticky

I have a sticky navigation bar (utilising this sticky.js plugin: http://stickyjs.com/) at the top of my web page that on a scrollTop position of 0px has a height of 141px. Once the user scrolls more than 100px vertically down the height of that navigation changes to 86px in a smooth transition. My problem is that when I scroll down the page to say 500px the navigation height changes fine, but if I reload the page (not through a hard refresh) the position of the screen stays the same but the height of the navigation is reloaded back to 141px and once a scroll of >=1px happens the navigation then changes height to 86px.

Is it possible that on a (non hard) refresh the browser checks the current scrollTop position of the page, and then changes the height of the sticky navigation to 86px before its actually visible to the user?

Here is my JS:

```
$(window).load(function() {

        $(window).scroll(function() {

        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (scroll >= 100) {
            $('.nav').addClass('smaller');
        } else {
            $('.nav').removeClass('smaller');
        }
        });

    });
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.nav {
    height: 141px;
    z-index: 99999;
    width: 100%;
    background: #ea1593;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: 0.3s ease-in-out all;
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease-in-out all;
}

/* ScrollTop class change for nav height */
.smaller {
    background: #db0e87;
    height: 86px;
}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<nav class="nav"></nav>
```

Comment: I have just checked this on IE 8 - 11 and it works but on the first scroll movement both the logo and menu jump to the top and back to their original position for a split second. Anyone know why this is? I'm fairly new to javascript.

Comment: In regards to the top comment this has now been fixed when removing the sticky nav plugin and opting for a position fixed nav.